Firestore React Js Increment Value by FieldValue without Google Cloud Function
Is there a way to increment integer by FieldValue without having to deal with HTTP, Google Cloud Function?
And if there is, may I ask how? Because I kept getting error from this "firestore is not defined, firebase is not defined, admin is not defined, FieldValue is not defined" even though I tried to import to the project already.
import { db } from "../utils/firebase.js"

import {
  collection,
  doc,
  setDoc,
  getDocs,
  getDoc,
  deleteDoc,
  onSnapshot,
  updateDoc,
  query,
  limit,
  where,
  increment,
  FieldValue,
} from "firebase/firestore"
 
export async function increaseStock(data) {
  const queryCompanyProduct = query(collection(db, "order"))
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "order", data.id), {
    grandtotal: FieldValue.increment(50), 
    // I tried firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(50) = also error..    
  })
}


Did you try to use grandtotal: increment(50) and remove FieldValue from the import?

Alex Mamo who read my mind again. Thank you so much

May I ask a question for my knowledge? I really did try to research and spend hours before posting anything. But I think my learning is limited by experience in reading document. For example, I follow the link to "documentation" posted by Dong [link]https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value . However, in the link it show to type FieldValue.  is there a filter in the page regardering old modular API  / new API ?  All i can see is filter for different coding language

It's good to hear that you made it work again :) I'm not sure I understand what is the issue with the docs. If you think something is wrong, you can report that to the Firebase team.

Follow the example in the documentation.  There is no need to import or use FieldValue directly when using the newer modular API.
import { query, collection, doc, updateDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";

const queryCompanyProduct = query(collection(db, "order"))
await updateDoc(doc(db, "order", data.id), {
  grandtotal: increment(50), 
})

